# RSpec doesn't return Hash field to Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, rspec

So I'm running a #create test in my Rails API, but somehow one field in the Factory which is a Hash doesn't reach the Controller for an INSERT.

Factory

```
    factory :child do
        id 5
        type "type1"
        vars { var1: 1, var2: 2 }
        values { value1: 1, value2: 2 }
    end
```

Test

```
    it "creates child with associated id" do
        Rails::logger.info "Testing CREATE"
        child = FactoryGirl.build(:child).attributes
        Rails::logger.info "INITIAL:"
        Rails::logger.info child
        post :create, :parent => @parent_id, :child => child
        expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
    end
```

Controller Action

```
def create
    @parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id])
    @child = @parent.childs.build(child_params)

    if @child.save
      render json: @child, status: 201
    else
      render json: { error: "404: Not Found" }.to_json, status: 404 #just to know, this error will be changed
    end
end

(...) some code here

def child_params
  params.require(:child).permit(:id, :type, :parent_id) #here I've also tried to include :vars, :value unsuccessfully
end
```

Result

```
D, [2015-01-08T20:02:19.016182 #76314] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.9ms)  
INSERT INTO "childs" ("id", "type", "parent_id", "created_at", "updated_at") 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  
[["id", 1], ["type", "type1"], ["parent_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-01-08 20:02:19.010801"], ["updated_at", "2015-01-08 20:02:19.010801"]]
```

As you can see, the vars and values hashes are not read by the Controller. The RSpec test reads them fine:

```
I, [2015-01-08T20:02:18.989104 #76314]  INFO -- : 
{"id"=>1, "type"=>"type1", "vars"=>{"var1"=>"1", "var2"=>"2"}, "values"=>{"value1"=>"1", "value2"=>"2"}, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil, "parent_id"=>nil}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What does the definition of child look like? And why is the pluralization funky?

Comment: They were example names (child for Model and childs for Controller, don't mind them). Sorry but by definition of child, what do you mean?

Comment: I'm impressed that it doesn't crash for you, when you use { } in factory it is treated as a block, so you should rather do something like `vars { {va1: 'aaa', var2: 'sth'} }`

Comment: @Swistaku yeah, I forgot to point this out. It really doesn't seem to matter here, I've tried vars {}, vars {{ x: y }} and vars { { x: y } } and the result is always the same.

Comment: Do strong params allow for this (child_params method)? Can you show this method?

Comment: @Swistaku Just edited my question, see in the controller code. Really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment strong_params doesn't allow (AFAIK, and [according to this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454)) to permit hashes with unknown keys inside so you need to do in your strong params something like, if you know the keys

```
def child_params
  params.require(:sth).permit(:id, :type, :parent_id, vars: [:var1, :var2], values: [:value1, :value2]) 
end
```

or simply do

```
def child_params
  params.require(:sth).permit!
end
```

Here's live from my console

```
[7] pry(#<Admin::SampleController>)> params.require(:sth).permit(:type, vars: [:var1, :var2])
Unpermitted parameters: id, values, created_at, updated_at, parent_id
=> {"type"=>"type1", "vars"=>{"var1"=>"1", "var2"=>"2"}}
[8] pry(#<Admin::SampleController>)> params.require(:sth).permit(:type, vars: [[]])
Unpermitted parameters: var1, var2
Unpermitted parameters: id, values, created_at, updated_at, parent_id
=> {"type"=>"type1", "vars"=>{}}
[9] pry(#<Admin::SampleController>)> params.require(:sth).permit!
=> {"id"=>1,
 "type"=>"type1",
 "vars"=>{"var1"=>"1", "var2"=>"2"},
 "values"=>{"value1"=>"1", "value2"=>"2"},
 "created_at"=>nil,
 "updated_at"=>nil,
 "parent_id"=>nil}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you very, very much for your effort! I've been really struggling with this and that's the solution. (Sorry for not upvoting your answer, don't have enough rep yet)

Comment: On the issue I've referenced there are also some neat ideas how to solve this problem :)

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at it. Thanks one more time :)

Comment: btw, check out [selleo-controller_tests gem](https://github.com/Selleo/selleo-controller_tests) for controller testing ;)

Comment: That seems a pretty nice gem. I'll definitely give it a try when I'm done with this project :) perphaps include it in my work from now on.